# Warning in list initialization in C++11

Tags: c++11, type-conversion

This is my code :

```
int x=65;
char ch{x};
```

And this is the warning when compiled with `-std=C++11 flag:

```
Narrowed conversion from "int to char"
```

But I think there should be an error as `x` is not a constant and we are initializing `ch with a non-constant value.` What actually happens?

Comment: Why would/should you be unable to initialize `ch` with a variable?

Comment: @MagnusHoff C++11 disallows narrowing conversions in `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clang will give you an error:

```
main.cpp:23:9: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'char' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
```

gcc as far as I remember decided to issue warning as there is too many source code that would be broken by such decision.

when you initialize variable using uniform initialization then narrowing conversions are forbidden.

Comment: That means if x was a const, then it still be an error/wa for narrowing conversion?

Comment: @dlpcoder yes, but only if its value is in the range of the variable type which is being initialized. For example `const int x=65;` will be OK, but `const int x=65000;`will generate error. When variable is constant expression Value range is checked at compilation time. I dont know where this is explained in standard, but here rather `constexpr` is required, for example `void foo(const int n) { char ch{n}; }` will also fail, even though `n` is const.

Comment: 'cause in the last case, the compiler do not know about the value of n being passed. It may be out a narrowing conversion. Hence will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the standard treats this as an error, and allows implementations to flat out reject this code.

However, implementations are almost never *required* to reject code that does not conform to the standard. They have to diagnose the problem, but if they attach the label "warning" to it and continue to accept the code, there is no problem.

In this case, C++11 made perfectly well-formed C++03 code into an error (not entirely your code, but `char ch[] = {x};` used to be valid), so compilers have a good reason to treat it as only a warning: they want to accept as much formerly valid code as reasonable, or users might have a good reason to switch to another compiler.